# iOS how to build libflac in Xcode 4 for 5.0

Tags: xcode, ios5

While trying to compile libflac using gas preprocessor and alternative conf string I get C compiler failure both with
./configure --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' --enable-neon --disable-debug

and 
./configure --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' --enable-neon --disable-debug

ld: in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with 'sysroot'. It gives access to ../usr/lib/* but not ../usr/lib/system. A temporary hack is -L$ISYSROOT/usr/lib/system but feels quite yucky.